# Can't find infinite loop cause

Tags: php, functions, loop, save-post

I am working on the below function which will eventually create a set of posts based on meta data entered into a "parent" post. I'm running into an infinite loop when hitting the save button, which I know is often caused by using `wp_update_post` or `wp_save_post` while hooking into `save_post` action. I've removed the action temporarily at the top of the function, and re-added it at the end in the hopes of preventing that, but it doesn't seem to have done so.

Can anyone see where I'm causing an infinite loop below?

```
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {
    remove_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post'); //remove action temporarily to prevent infinite loops!

    //All the dates saved in the repeater field
    $chosenDates = get_field('add_dates_and_times', $post_id); //timestamp

    //Get duration of event and multiply by 60 to get seconds
    $duration = get_field('event_duration', $post_id); //duration in minutes
    $duration = ($duration * 60); //duration in seconds

    //Get any event posts that have the ac_parent_id that matches the current parent post
    $currentChildEvents = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'meta_key' => 'ac_parent_post',
                'meta_value' => $post_id,
                )
            ),
        ));
    $hasChildren = have_posts($currentChildEvents); //true/false
    if ($hasChildren) {
            $existingDates = array();
        while($hasChildren) {
            the_post();
            $existingDate = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_EventStartDate', true);
            $existingDates[] = strtotime($existingDate['0']); //timestamp
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    $datesNeedEvents = array_diff($chosenDates, $existingDates); //All the timestamps that need events created for them



    //check if the repeater has any values entered
    if (have_rows('add_dates_and_times', $post_id)) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'is_ac_parent_event', true); //Since we have some dates, make this event a parent
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'ac_child_dates', $chosenDates); //Set the array of child dates as a meta value in the parent post
            $count = 0;
        while (have_rows('add_dates_and_times', $post_id)) { //Loop through each date in repeater
        the_row();


            $dateTime = get_sub_field('date_and_time'); //timestamp
            $startDate = date('Y-m-d', $dateTime);

            $startHour = date('h', $dateTime);
            $startMinute = date('i', $dateTime);
            $startMeridian = date('a', $dateTime);

            $endStamp = ($dateTime+$duration);
            $endDate = date('Y-m-d', $endStamp);
            $endHour = date('h', $endStamp);
            $endMinute = date('i', $endStamp);
            $endMeridian = date('a', $endStamp);
            $count++;
            if ($count == 1) { //This is the first date listed, so we update the parent post with its info
                $updateCurrent = array (
                    'post_title' => get_the_title($post_id),
                    //'post_content' => ac_get_the_content($post_id),
                    'EventStartDate' => $startDate,
                   'EventEndDate' => $endDate,
                   'EventStartHour' => $startHour,
                   'EventStartMinute' => $startMinute,
                   'EventStartMeridian' => $startMeridian,
                   'EventEndHour' => $endHour,
                   'EventEndMinute' => $endMinute,
                   'EventEndMeridian' => $endMeridian,
                );
                tribe_update_event($post_id, $updateCurrent);
            } else {
                if (in_array($dateTime, $datesNeedEvents)) {
                    $newEvent = array(
                        'post_title' => get_the_title($post_id),
                        //'post_content' => ac_get_the_content($post_id),
                        'EventStartDate' => $startDate,
                       'EventEndDate' => $endDate,
                       'EventStartHour' => $startHour,
                       'EventStartMinute' => $startMinute,
                       'EventStartMeridian' => $startMeridian,
                       'EventEndHour' => $endHour,
                       'EventEndMinute' => $endMinute,
                       'EventEndMeridian' => $endMeridian,
                       //'Venue' => array(
                        //'Venue' => 'Some Place',
                        //  'Country' => 'US',
                        //  'Address' => '1 W. Washington Ave.',
                        //  'City' => 'Madison',
                        //  'State' => 'WI'     
                       //),
                    );
                    $newEvent = tribe_create_event($newEvent);
                    update_post_meta($newEvent, 'ac_parent_event', $post_id);
                }
            }
        }
    } else { //No dates present in repeater
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'ac_parent_event', false); //We set this to false, just in case it was true before
    }
    add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post'); //re-add action to continue
    if (!is_admin) {
        wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('url').'/events/community/edit/event/'.$post_id); exit;
    }
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);
```

Comment: if `$hasChildren` is true, `while($hasChildren)` will never evaluate to false and you'll never exit that loop, the value is never changed. refer to the loop example on [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage) for correct use.

Comment: And, to clarify: tribe_update_event() and tribe_create_event() are basically the same as wp_update_post() and wp_insert_post(), they are just wrappers for those functions that do a few extra things with meta fields before saving/creating the post

Comment: Ah, I see now. I was jumbling up get_posts and wp_query usage! Thank you.